# Именование пакетов Golang

Tags: golang

Есть ли соглашения по именованию пакетов в golang?

Comment: Не понимаю, почему кто-то хочет вопрос закрыть. Объясню, что вопрос несёт объективные знания и я его добавил потому, что сам не раз гуглил его и находил не то,а также ссылался в диалоге с кем-то на данное соглашение и его приходилось искать. База знаний ruSO как раз подходит для этой ситуации

Comment: Закрыть предложил я, ибо нейминг - это либо вкусовщина, либо прописано в стайл гайде проекта.

Comment: Кроме того, ответ находится гуглением в один прием: https://go.dev/blog/package-names

Comment: @PakUula далеко не вкусовщина, а необходимость писать понятный код. Про соглашения надо знать и использовать. Поэтому вопросу тут место.

Comment: так же полезно : https://habr.com/ru/articles/441842/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соглашения по выбору имен пакетов 
Разработчикам, использующим пакет, придется вводить его имя каждый раз, когда они вызывают функцию из этого пакета. (Вспомните fmt.Printf, fmt.Println, fmt.Print и т. д.)
Чтобы не возникало проблем, при выборе имен пакетов следует соблюдать несколько правил:
• Имя пакета должно быть записано только символами нижнего регистра.
• Имя следует сокращать, если его смысл очевиден (например, fmt).
• По возможности имя должно состоять из одного слова. Если необходимы два слова, они
не должны разделяться символами подчеркивания, а второе слово не должно начинаться
с буквы верхнего регистра (пример — пакет strconv).
• Импортированные имена пакетов могут конфликтовать с именами локальных перемен-
ных, поэтому не используйте имя, которое с большой вероятностью может быть выбрано
пользователями пакета. (Например, если бы пакет fmt назывался format, то импорт этого
пакета создавал бы риск конфликта с локальной переменной format.)

Источник : Head First. Изучаем Go. — СПб.: Питер, 2020. — 544 с.: ил. — (Серия «Head First O’Reilly»).
ISBN 978-5-4461-1395-8

Comment: Источник указывать, по-моему, не обязательно.